# phpDaemon на Amazon EC2

Tags: php, ubuntu, websocket, amazon

Поставил phpDaemon на Amazon EC2, система Ubuntu 14.04.

Вот конфиг демона:

```
user www-data;
group www-data;

max-workers 8;
min-workers 1;
start-workers   1;
max-idle    0;

path 'conf/AppResolver.php';

Pool:Servers\WebSocket {
    enable 1;
    listen 'tcp://0.0.0.0';
    port 8047;
}

Pool:Servers\HTTP {
    enable 1;
    privileged;
    listen 'tcp://0.0.0.0';
    port 8080;
}

\PHPDaemon\Examples\Example {
    enable 1;
}

\PHPDaemon\Examples\ExampleWebSocket {
    enable 1;
}
```

Вроде бы простой пример. На "амазоне" открыты порты ssh и http, то есть 22 и 80. При подключении выдает time out. Включил все tcp-порты, та же пробема.

Как решить данную проблему?

Ссылка на phpDaemon: https://github.com/kakserpom/phpdaemon

Comment: если там действительно стоит операционная система *gnu/linux*, то *обратные слэши* `\ ` в ней интерпретируются не как разделители пути, а как *escape-символы*. для разделения же частей пути в этой операционной системе используется *слэш*: `/`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, здесь это скорее не для указания пути, а для поиска PHP класса. Типа "namespace Library\Examples". Ну в примерах автора указано именно так.

Comment: я указал на явную бросающуюся в глаза ошибку, а как с ней поступить — решать, конечно, только вам.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, это не ошибка, это namespace separator

Comment: @Etki, если программа, читающая этот файл, может «справиться» с такими *escape*-последовательностями — это хорошо.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin for teh last time - это **не** escape-последовательности

Comment: @Etki, да, вы правы. спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

1. следует убедиться, запущена ли ваша программа, и, при необходимости, запустить её. см. вывод:

   ```
   $ ps aux
   ```
2. следует убедиться, что она слушает указанные порты. см. вывод:

   ```
   $ sudo lsof -Pn -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN
   ```

   если не слушает, следует проанализировать её логи — вероятно, там указана причина «неслушания».
3. если запущена и слушает, то следует обратиться в техподдержку компании, предоставившей хостинг (в вашем случае, как я понимаю, *amazon*).